# Documentation page always opens at the bottom

Tags: r, rgui

When I open a help page in RGui (R 3.3.2 on Windows 7) using the text help page viewer, it is opened at the bottom of the help page. See the screenshot below after typing `?help`, where the scrollbar of the help page is at the bottom. Is there a way to change the behaviour such that help pages are openend at the *beginning* rather than at the end?

[image: Screenshot of help page viewer]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
help(help, help_type = "html")
```

Since, you might have older version of R. it's default help type might be "text" which takes you to the end of the page which is in text form. Use help_type as "html"

> Note that options(help_type = "html") must be set to actually make use
>   of HTML help, although it might be the default for an R installation.

Read [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.1/topics/help)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I prefer the text version of the help, which I think I could choose as the default when I installed RGui (it has been a while). I remember that this opened at the top (my expected behaviour) in previous R installation I had on my computer.